# Setting multiple rows with different values

Tags: t-sql

im trying to write a stored procedure with this sort of pseudocode:

If ID from import table exists in Core Table
Then Update Core Table With the RowID from Table 1

I dont know if im just stuck in my head a bit, or I need to be using other tools to accomplish this, (cursor, cte?) here is what I have so far:

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT Core.ID 
          FROM Core, L1 
          WHERE Core.ID = RIGHT(L1_.ReferenceNo,5))

    UPDATE Core

    SET DuplicationRef = L1.RowID
    SELECT L1.RowID
    FROM Core core
    INNER JOIN L1 ON core.ID = RIGHT(L1.ReferenceNo,5)
```

Comment: Anything need to happen if the ID from the import table is not in the Core table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Merge targettable as a
Using sourcetable as b
On a.id = b.ReferenceNo

When matched then
Update set DuplicationRef = b.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for!